# How to print the nth number of the series?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to print the nth number of the series

2,23,235,2357,235711,23571113...

but i am not getting the right output after n=3.

At n=3 it's giving 234 which is wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

main()
{
    unsigned int t, n, p, i, j, d;
    int s;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    if (t <= 10)
    {
        while (t != 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &n);
            p = n;
            j = 2;
            s = 0;
            while (p > 0)
            {
                d = prime(j);
                // printf("%d",d);
                if (d == 1)
                {
                    s = s + j * pow(10, p - 1);
                    p--;
                    j++;
                }
                else
                    j++;
            }
            printf("%d", s);
            t--;
        }

    }

}

int prime(int num)
{
    int i, flag = 1, n;

    // n=sqrt(num);
    for (i = 2; (i <= num / 2) && (flag == 1); i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
            flag = 0;
    }
    if (flag == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

I am trying to generate a prime number after each iteration.

Comment: Did you think of integer overflow? Tried switching to `long long`?

Comment: have you considered using the debugger? Go on! You'll love using it.

Comment: yes i did long long but its giving me wrong answer at n=3 itself.

Comment: Why don't you just print the first n primes with no space between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're generating primes and want to output strings of the concatenated primes.

Write a function filling an array with the first n primes. That's easy.
Then you write an output function like:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        printf("%d", arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n"); /* or any other separator */
}
```

No trouble any more with large numbers, until you reach primes in the order of magnitude of a billion.

Comment: but i need to print the number,by doing what you have suggested nth term wont be a number,it would be the series of digits

Comment: Why the unnecessary step of filling an array?

Comment: @user39555  What is "235711" if not a series of digits?

Comment: Thank you molbdnilo :-) "235711" is nothing more than a series of digits. But to answer your question: he seems to nee something like 2,23,235,... so he needs to iterate over the array of primes over and over again. Storing them costs less than calculating them.

Answer (score 1):

In some low-quality C implementations, the `pow` function does not return a correct result even when the mathematical result is exactly representable in the floating-point format. E.g., `pow(10, 2)` may return 99.9999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 instead of 100.

When a floating-point value that is not an integer is assigned to an integer object, the value is converted to an integer by truncation. Thus, for example, 234.9999847412109375 would become 234.

Generally, you should avoid using floating-point functions such as `pow` for integer arithmetic. However, for reasonably small values where you know the result of `pow` should be exactly an integer, you can correct the result by using `round`: `round(pow(10, p - 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any extra space and inbuilt function !

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isPrime(int p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i*i<=p;i++)
    if(p%i==0)
    return 0;
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int n=10,count=0,p=2;
    while(count<n)
    {
        if(isPrime(p))
        {
            printf("%d",p);
            count++;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

even you can get rid of "count" variable by decrementing 'n'. and optimize this code by considering the fact that even numbers are not prime number (or all prime numbers are of the form of 6n+1 or 6n-1 ).